how to calculate the amount?
In postgresql using query
WITH RECURSIVE rel_rec AS (
    SELECT
            1 AS depth,
            *,
            ARRAY[lvl] AS child_path
        FROM types_of_work
        WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND project_id = 14

        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            nlevel(r.path) + 1,
            n.*,
            r.child_path || n.lvl
        FROM rel_rec AS r
        JOIN types_of_work AS n ON n.parent_id = r.tow_id
        WHERE r.project_id = 14
)
SELECT
    t0.tow_id,
    t0.project_id,
    t0.path,
    t0.child_path,
    t0.lvl,
    t0.parent_id,
    t0.depth,
    t2.tow_cost
FROM rel_rec t0
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        tow_id,
        tow_cost,
        tow_cost_percent,
        tow_date_start,
        tow_date_finish
    FROM tows_contract
    WHERE contract_id = 10
) AS t2 ON t0.tow_id = t2.tow_id
ORDER BY t0.child_path, t0.lvl;

we get a table



tow_id integer
path   ltree
child_path   smallint[]
lvl  smallint
parent_id   integer
depth   integer
cost   numeric
CUMULATIVE_COST




39
root
{1}
1
null
1

∑ 90


40
root.39
{1,2}
2
39
2
10



131
root.39
{1,3}
3
39
2
10



41
root.39
{1,4}
4
39
2
10



46
root.39
{1,5}
5
39
2

∑ 60


47
root.39.46
{1,5,6}
6
46
3

∑ 30


48
root.39.46.47
{1,5,6,7}
7
47
4

∑ 10


134
root.39.46.47.48
{1,5,6,7,8}
8
48
5
10



49
root.39.46.47
{1,5,6,9}
9
47
4
10



125
root.39.46.47
{1,5,6,10}
10
47
4
10



132
root.39.46
{1,5,11}
11
46
3

∑ 20


133
root.39.46.132
{1,5,11,12}
12
132
4
10



135
root.39.46.132
{1,5,11,13}
13
132
4
10



136
root.39.46
{1,5,14}
14
46
3

∑ 10


657
root.39.46.136
{1,5,14,15}
15
136
4
10



142
root
{16}
16
null
1

∑ 30


143
root.142
{16,17}
17
142
2

∑ 30


178
root.142.143
{16,17,18}
18
143
3
10



146
root.142.143
{16,17,19}
19
143
3
10



147
root.142.143
{16,17,20}
20
143
3
10



42
root
{21}
21
null
1

∑ 10


43
root.39.42
{21,22}
22
42
2

∑ 10


45
root.39.42.43
{21,22,23}
23
43
3

∑ 10


671
root.39.42.43.45
{21,22,23,24}
24
45
4

∑ 10


672
root.39.42.43.45.671
{21,22,23,24,25}
25
671
5
10




How to add the calculated sum of the costs of all nested children to this table? An example of this sum is the CUMULATIVE_COST column.
The table presented is a tree system.
The depth column shows the nesting level
The parent_id column shows the tow_id of the parent entity
minimal, reproducible example:
CREATE TABLE types_of_work (
    tow_id integer,
    path ltree,
    lvl integer,
    project_id integer,
    parent_id  integer
);
CREATE TABLE tows_contract (
    tow_id integer,
    cost integer,
    contract_id integer
);

INSERT INTO types_of_work (tow_id, path, project_id, lvl, parent_id)
    VALUES (39, 'root', 14, 1, null),
    VALUES (40, 'root.39', 14, 2, 39),
    VALUES (131, 'root.39', 14, 3, 39),
    VALUES (41, 'root.39', 14, 5, 39),
    VALUES (46, 'root.39', 14, 5, 39),
    VALUES (47, 'root.39.46', 14, 6, 46),
    VALUES (48, 'root.39.46.47', 14, 7, 47),
    VALUES (134, 'root.39.46.47.48',  14, 8, 48),
    VALUES (49, 'root.39.46.47', 14, 9, 47),
    VALUES (125, 'root.39.46.47', 14, 10, 47),
    VALUES (132, 'root.39.46', 14, 11, 46),
    VALUES (133, 'root.39.46.132', 14, 12, 132),
    VALUES (135, 'root.39.46.132', 14, 13, 132),
    VALUES (136, 'root.39.46', 14, 14, 46),
    VALUES (657, 'root.39.46.132', 14, 15, 136),
    VALUES (142, 'root', 14, 16, null),
    VALUES (143, 'root.142', 14, 17, 142),
    VALUES (178, 'root.142.143', 14, 18, 143),
    VALUES (146, 'root.142.143', 14, 19, 143),
    VALUES (147, 'root.142.143', 14, 20, 143),
    VALUES (42, 'root', 14, 21, null),
    VALUES (43, 'root.42', 14, 22, 42),
    VALUES (45, 'root.42.43',  14, 23, 43),
    VALUES (671, 'root.42.43.45', 14, 24, 45),
    VALUES (672, 'root.42.43.45.671', 14, 25, 671)
;
INSERT INTO tows_contract (tow_id, cost, contract_id)
    VALUES (40, 10, 10),
    VALUES (131, 10, 10),
    VALUES (41, 10, 10),
    VALUES (134, 10, 10),
    VALUES (49, 10, 10),
    VALUES (125, 10, 10),
    VALUES (133, 10, 10),
    VALUES (135, 10, 10),
    VALUES (657, 10, 10),
    VALUES (178, 10, 10),
    VALUES (146, 10, 10),
    VALUES (147, 10, 10),
    VALUES (672, 10, 10)
;

as an option, you need to sum up the cost of all the following lines, while these lines have a greater depth value than the current one

What is in types_of_work? Please post a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

I added the code @Dogbert

Although this is a reproducible example, it is not minimal. The number of useful responses to a post tends to be inversely related to the size of the example (excluding the cases of missing, or inadequate, examples). Only include as much sample data and example output as necessary to clearly demonstrate the desired behavior.

I just need to understand where to look, I will bypass exceptions and errors myself

The code has multiple errors. There is no type for parent_id and the root.xyz are invalid syntax.

fixed bugs. Added data type for parent_id and added quotes for root.xyz

Join the table back to itself with the LTREE ancestor operator, <@
with costs as (
  select t.*, c.cost, c.contract_id, t.path||t.tow_id::text as fullpath
    from types_of_work t
         left join tows_contract c on c.tow_id = t.tow_id
)
select l.*, sum(r.cost) as cumulative_cost
  from costs l
       join costs r on r.fullpath <@ l.fullpath
 group by l.tow_id, l.path, l.fullpath, l.project_id, l.lvl, l.parent_id, 
          l.cost, l.contract_id
 order by l.path;

Working fiddle

Thank you very much! You helped me figure it out!

I changed the generation function for path so that it would take the form of your example fullpath
Using JOIN I found the sum, as in your example

